# Keep selected tab when click on browser back button or mobile back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using below html code for tabs in mobile view

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
                $('a.tab-menu').click(function(){
                    if ( $(window).width() < 768 ) 
                   $('#tab-'+($('.tab-menu').index($(this))+1)).slideToggle("slow").siblings('div').hide('slow');
                });
            });
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <h2 class="responsive-tab"><a href="#tab-1" class="tab-menu">tab 1</a></h2>
    <div id="tab-1"> content here </div>
    <h2 class="responsive-tab"><a href="#tab-2" class="tab-menu">tab 1</a></h2>
    <div id="tab-2"> content here </div>
    <h2 class="responsive-tab"><a href="#tab-3" class="tab-menu">tab 1</a></h2>
    <div id="tab-3"> <a href="#">link here</a> </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

My question how can I keep the selected tab if click on any link on selected tab and go to link and when I click on back button should back to selected tab

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the `location.hash` when the page is ready then trigger a click on that tab when the page is loaded.

```
$(function () {
  // Let's see if there's a hash in the url...
  var hash = location.hash;

  // If there is...
  if (hash) {

    //  Find the link that has the same href value
    // as the hash and fake a click on it...
    $('a').filter(function () {
      return this.href === hash;
    }).trigger('click');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer
you mean

$(function () {
  var hash = location.hash;
  if (hash) {
    $('a.tab-menu').filter(function () {
      return this.href === hash;
    }).trigger('click');
  }
});

Comment: thanks for your answer 

you mean 

$(function () {
  var hash = location.hash;
  if (hash) {
    $('a.tab-menu').filter(function () {
      return this.href === hash;
    }).trigger('click');
  }
});

Comment: Yeah, you can be as specific as you need to be.

Comment: Sorry I am not good in jQuery then the code will be

  $(document).ready(function(){
                $('a.tab-menu').click(function(){
                    if ( $(window).width() < 768 ) 
                   $('#tab-'+($('.tab-menu').index($(this))+1)).slideToggle("slow").siblings('div').hide('slow');
       
        var hash = location.hash;

        if (hash) {
            $('a').filter(function () {
      return this.href === hash;
    }).trigger('click');
  }
    
                });
            });

Comment: Yes, that looks about right. You might want to `console.log(this.href, hash)` to make sure they're exactly the same inside that filter function.